# Disabled button works fine in fire fox, but not in IE

Tags: java, asp.net, web

I have some code written in JAVA. On the webpage, a certain button is disabled but if I click on this disabled button, a pop-up will appear in Internet Explorer. The same code works fine in Firefox
Disabled button works fine in fire fox, it is disabled in IE also, but a click on disabled button in IE, pop-up comes which expected to come only when button is enabled.

Fire Fox Version - 14.0.1
IE - 7.0

code

```
 if(IbSilentState == "Yes" || IbPresentState == "Absent")
    {
            if(btnIbsPowerOn) btnIbsPowerOn.disabled = true;
            if(btnIbsPowerOff) btnIbsPowerOff.disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
            if(btnIbsPowerOn) btnIbsPowerOn.disabled = (IbPowerState == "On") ? true : false;
            if(btnIbsPowerOff) btnIbsPowerOff.disabled = (IbPowerState == "Stand-by off") ? true : false;
    }
    if(IbSilentState == "Yes" || TsmPresentState == "Absent")
    {
            if(btnTsmPowerOn) btnTsmPowerOn.disabled = true;
            if(btnTsmPowerOff) btnTsmPowerOff.disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
            if(btnTsmPowerOn) btnTsmPowerOn.disabled = (TsmPowerState == "On") ? true : false;
            if(btnTsmPowerOff) btnTsmPowerOff.disabled = (TsmPowerState == "Stand-by off") ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please reword your question. I can't make sense of what you're trying to ask

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript, not JAVA, right?

Comment: I think you need to show some more code. The above code looks like `Java`, but it really tells us nothing of value. Besides, if it works in `Firefox` but not in `Internet Explorer`, it has most likely to do with the `HTML` used to render the button disabled. Either the `Internet Explorer` doesn't like the `HTML` or it's simply a bug in `IE7`. So it would be interesting to know if you use a framework to generate the `HTML` and if you toggle the state of the button manually or if the framework does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how java applies to webpages unless you mean you've written an applet..? There shouldnt be any differences between different browsers in this case...

Anyway I have no idea what could be causing your problem, because I dont really understand it, but I did spot an error with your code that may or may not help...

You should never use `==` with strings, instead, do something like `"Yes".equals(IbSilentState)`

Comment: _There shouldnt be any differences between different browsers regardless..._ - in an ideal world maybe. In reality you will pretty much always find a difference in behavior between browsers. Each browser can interpret `HTML` pretty much how it wants. What they do is usually close to the specs but it's not uncommon to have small differences between browsers. That is because some are more lenient or strict than others. Or they simply choose to do it a little differently. Trying to _get it right_ on all browsers has been a nightmare for Web Developers for ages.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldnt have used the word regardless... What I meant was there shouldnt be any difference in the way an applet works between browsers (beyond getting it to run in the first place that is, that can be quite a mess).There certainly are loads of differences between browsers interpreting HTML.